# Adding a CNAME to Vue.js Project

Tags: vue.js, github-pages, cname

I am trying to add a CNAME file to a Vue.js project (vue cli tool) so that it deploys in the root folder. I am hosting with gh-pages, but cannot seem to get my gh-pages branch to contain the CNAME file correctly. My current folder structure.

```
|-site-folder
|  |-build
|  |-config
|  |-dist
|  |-build
|  |-node-modules
|  |-src
|  |  |-CNAME
|  |-static
|-index.html
|-package.json
|-(ect..)
```

Answer (score 0):

CNAME file needs to go in /dist folder. I now know what the /dist folder is, lol.